# Allow Kendo UI splitter to resize only to the right

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI interface as the following:

[image]

I want to make box 5 be able to resize only to the right side. how can I do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to manually check panes width:

```
var size = 0;
var splitter = $("#splitter");
splitter.kendoSplitter({
  panes: [ { collapsible: true }, {} ],
  resize: function(e) {
    if (splitter.find(".k-pane:first").width() >= size)
    {
      size = splitter.find(".k-pane:first").width();
    } else {
      splitterData.size(".k-pane:first", size);
    }
  }
});
var splitterData = splitter.data('kendoSplitter');
```

Comment: Where can I find more documentations?

Comment: This is mix of Kendo feature: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/splitter#methods-size and jQuery selectiors and DOM operataions: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

Set the max property of Fifth 5 pane to some value , so that I will not be able to resize to the 4th pane